# How do i select similar sides of a face loop

Tags: faces, selection-tools

How do i select all faces going along the edge of this shape? 
Is there an easier way than actually panning the camera around 360 degrees, and stopping intermittently to SHIFT+click another face into the selection????

This is so tedious to do when extruding faces then remapping the extrusion onto a UV.

[image: ce]
^^^ Ideally I want a way where I can only select 1 face and it knows to 'go-along' all the connecting edges and loop back around and select them all for me to use.

Comment: `Alt+Click` around the edge doesn't work? (It does work from the mesh which you have created: https://imgur.com/2VwABjk)

Comment: it goes the other way... e.g it selects that big fat main face instead of the small side one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the face with edge loop select <kbd>Alt + LMB</kbd>:

[image]

Click the side you want them to propagate, ideally on the edge (the red circle position).

Sometime it won't propagate correctly, the you might need to switch between face and edge select mode until one is working correclty. If none of them work, then their must be some topology issue that cannot treat those face as a loop (eg. got a diverse face in middle)